# output script execution to log file on windows not created

Tags: oracle, qt, qt5

In fact, from my Qt5 application, I'm executing an SQL script and I want to trace output results to a log file to know if there's any error.
I'm exectuting the following command

```
sqlplus myUser/user_pwd@orcl @"path_to_script\script_ora.sql" >"path_to_log\exec_script.log"
```

but the log file is not created and I really don't why.
Can anyone tell what I'm missing.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What operating system are you using? I just tested this myself on my Windows machine and it worked properly.  Do you have `exit;` or `quit;` at the end of your SQL script? Does the user you are logged in as have write access to the directory you are trying to write the log file to?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. The command works fine on cmd bach but not from Qt5 application.
Yes, the user have all permissions to write on the log folder.